# Can't use launchctl as non-root user

Tags: macos, homebrew, user-account, launchd

I was trying to set up the [grooved](https://github.com/ghedo/grooved) - a music player daemon. It works over `dbus` which I installed through Homebrew.

In the caveats of the `dbus` formula it says:

```
To start dbus: brew services start dbus
```

When I try to run this exact command I get

```
/Users/user/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.dbus.plist: Operation not permitted
==> Successfully started `dbus` (label: homebrew.mxcl.dbus)
```

Running the same command with `sudo` works just fine. But I don't think this can be the solution to this. Also I want to use `dbus` to communicate with `grooved` using my user account and not root.

I tried loading and starting `plist` files by hand. Making sure they are in the right location (`/Users/user/Library/LaunchAgents`) with the right permissions/ownership:

```
.rw-------      user staff  homebrew.mxcl.dbus.plist
.rw-r--r--      user staff  local.grooved.plist
```

It's the same. I can't use `launchctl` with my non-root user.

Interstingly using the new commands things work:

```
$ launchctl bootstrap gui/501 ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.dbus.plist
$ launchctl kickstart gui/501/homebrew.mxcl.dbus
$ launchctl bootout gui/501 ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.dbus.plist
```

I don't need to run these as root. But `grooved` can't see the `dbus`:

```
Error creating dbus service: Could not get session bus: dbus: couldn't determine address of session bus
```

If somebody could point me into the right direction where the problem could be...
It can't all be a bug in `grooved` because `launchctl` doesn't seem to work correctly for me.

---

This is El Capitan 10.11.6